# Child div appearing outside parent div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to place a div that contains a picture into another div. This parent
div also has 2 other divs inside which work perfectly.
My html code for the parent and child divs is:

```
     <div id="contentsWrapper">
     <div><ul id="sideNav">
         <li><a href="linkone.html" id="linkone">One</a></li>
         <li><a href="linktwo.html" id="linktwo">Two</a></li>
     </ul></div>

     <div id="text">
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, <br />
         sed diam nonummy  nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna.
     </div>

     <div id="picture">
          <img src="picture.jpg" alt="picture" height="200" width="200" />
     </div>
</div>
```

The CSS code is

```
#contentsWrapper {
    width: 800px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

#sideNav {
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    width: 160px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #999;
    position: absolute;
 }
 #text {
    width: 375px;
    margin-left: 180px;
    font-weight: bold;
 }
 #picture {
    position: absolute;
    width: 225px;
    margin-left: 575px;
    background-color: #FFFF00;
 }
```

But this always places the picture in the correct position from the left side of the screen but below the contentsWrapper div.
I have tried using just text and changed the width and margin-left valuesfor the picture div but it still comes out with the same result.

Comment: And where do you want to see it?

Answer (score 1):

Absolute positioning removes it from the container. Try something like this instead:

```
#picture {
width: 225px;
float:right;
background-color: #FFFF00;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Add `float:left; in the #text` style get work....

```
#text {
    width: 375px;
    margin-left: 180px;
    font-weight: bold;
    float:left;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is doing exactly what you tell him to do. But maybe I just don't understand what you are planning to do (maybe add an image?)

First question: why are you using `position:absolute` on the image? this removes it from the flow.

Second question: why are you using `position:absolute` together with `margin-left` and not `left`?

And if you are using left then, it will calculate it from it's parent if you give `position:relative` to the parrent.

Answer (score 0):

Either you should remove the position:absolute or give position:relative to parent div.

And why there are huge margin?

```
#contentsWrapper {
    width: 800px;
    margin-left: 10px; background:red; position:relative; overflow: hidden; height:auto
}

#sideNav {
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    width: 160px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #999;
    float:left
 }
 #text {
    width: 375px;
    font-weight: bold; float:left
 }
 #picture {
    width: 225px;
    background-color: #FFFF00; float:left
 }
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ZyptN/)**